# set a relationship in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, relationship

Yes, i know there's lots of this questions about jpa and foreign keys
But i dont found any answer for my case.

I need to import json data in a mysql database. The data looks like this example

order -(1:n)> item

```json
{
  type: "order",
  name: "abcd",
  business_key: "2020_0001",
}

[
{
  type: "item",
  desc: "xxxx",
  business_key: "2020_0001",
  date: "2020-01-01",
},

{
  type:"item",
  desc: "aaaaa",
  business_key: "2020_0001",
  date: "2020-01-01",
}
]
```

The business_key is in the old datasource the foreign key.

What i tried was to create a java entity class for order with a oneToMany items.

```java
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "business_key")
    private String businessKey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "business_key")
    private String businessKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Order order;
}
```

And here is the part to insert the data in the database

```java
private void processObjectMapping(String className, File file) throws IOException {
        if (className.matches("^item.json$")) {
            List<Item> list = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<Item>>() {
            });
            itemRepository.saveAll(list);
        } else if (className.matches("^order.json$")) {
            Order order = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Order>() {
            });
    orderRepository.save(order);
    }
```

Of course the JPA cant insert a value in the Foreign_key column all objects were created independently.

*Question:* is there a way to build a relationship between the entities in jpa with the existing business_key.
Or what i thought is to run after the import is done a process which set the releationships?
Could help me here a JPA Entity Graph?
Or maybe other recommendations?

Comment: Can you please show code for the example, how you try to insert the data now?

Comment: I'm not sure how you haven't found an answer - every JPA tutorial that deals with an object model (ie relationships) normally have to explain this in detail. I don't know why you'd have businessKey duplicated in all your entities in this graph - it seems very denormalized; why didn't you use is as the order ID? JPA would then set this in the Items for you based on the relationship instead of you having to generate something entirely different. Otherwise, I don't see why you'd have it in Item at all.